# Default fields not loading in Freeform Pro

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, fieldtype

I've just upgraded from Freeform to Freeform Pro so I could make use of the additional fieldtypes, but on installation of Pro I still only have four fieldtypes (text, text area, upload and mailing list).

I've tried a complete uninstall of freeform, deleting the third party folders and reinstalling fresh, but I still only get 4 field types.

I can see that all the fieldtypes exist as php files within the 'default_fields' folder, but they aren't appearing within the module in EE.

Any help?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Did you upgrade to Freeform Pro **4.1.7** (latest version as of this writing)? Have you checked file permissions? Finally, check that code within the uploaded files match the code from a fresh Freeform file package. I have heard of certain FTP clients/setups that can add junk/modify code files sometimes (although that usually triggers errors).

Comment: Came in to work this morning and it all seemed to be fine. Perhaps it was just a caching issue. Thanks for the help though - much appreciated.